# undefined references

Tags: c++, netbeans, compilation, static-libraries

I used a static library provided by a client, and the library is not named as "lib*.a", then how to use it when I compile.

I tried to add it as library(similar to "-l*"), but then I got -l* not found, I guess it's because it tried to find a "lib*.a".

Then I put the file name with it's absolute path in the command line as a parameter, then i got "linker input file unused because linking not done", and lots of undefined references. I also tried command line to compile the cpp file, and I can get the object file without any warning or errors.

My question is how to build the project with this kind of library in Netbeans?

Another question is in the terminal, what to do after I get the object file? This one may be a little stupid, but I am new to c++, so hopefully anyone could help me with this since I am really confused and couldn't find any straight answer in google.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

rename the library to `libwhatever.a` then link using `-L /path/to/whatever -lwhatever`.

Comment: This is actually the most awesome answer I've ever seen on SO. xD

Comment: thanks, I tried that, it doesn't work. I got skipping incompatible libwhatever.a when searching -lwhatever

Comment: @leo what architecture are you using? As an example, the library could have been built for ppc64, but you may be linking without the `-m64` flag.

Comment: I think you hit the point. I tried again, this time I get error like this "/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `whatever.a(whatever.o)' is incompatible with i386 output" I am not familiar with the architecture, could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @leo try compiling and linking with the `-m64` flag

Answer (score 1):

> Then I put the file name with it's absolute path in the command line as a parameter, then i got "linker input file unused because linking not done".

Sounds like you specified the library when compiling, but you need to specify it when linking instead:

```
$ ls
main.cpp Makefile test.cpp
$ show test.cpp main.cpp Makefile
### test.cpp
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 void f() {
  3   puts("Hello, world!");
  4 }
### main.cpp
  1 void f();
  2 int main() {
  3   f();
  4   return 0;
  5 }
### Makefile
  1 main: main.cpp foo.a
  2 foo.a(test.o): test.o
  3 foo.a: foo.a(test.o)
$ make
g++    -c -o test.o test.cpp
ar rv foo.a test.o
ar: creating foo.a
a - test.o
g++     main.cpp foo.a   -o main
$ ./main
Hello, world!
```

If your makefile uses LDLIBS when compiling, which it probably does by default, then you can add foo.a to LDLIBS.  I didn't do that above for the sake of a simpler example.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're using a *nix compiler.

Try to specify the library path to the invocation that performs the linking.

Apparently you have specified it to an invocation with "-c" option, which doesn't link (compile only).

**EDIT**: example (including erors):

```
Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo
$ mkdir lib; cd lib

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo/lib
$ cat >foo.cpp
int foo() { return 42; }

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo/lib
$ g++ -c foo.cpp

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo/lib
$ ar -s foolib.a foo.o
ar: 'foolib.a': No such file

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo/lib
$ ar -rs foolib.a foo.o
ar: creating foolib.a

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo/lib
$ ls
foo.cpp  foo.o  foolib.a

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo/lib
$ cd ..

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo
$ cat >main.cpp
extern int foo();
#include <iostream>
int main()
{ std::cout << foo() << std::endl; }

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo
$ g++ -c main.cpp

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo
$ g++ main.o lib/foolib.a

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo
$ a
bash: a: command not found

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo
$ ./a
42

Alf@SpringFlower ~/leo
$ _
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Well, I tried with -g, and then errors occur even in the command line. undefined references everywhere I call the method from the lib. I specify the directory in the linker, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I specify the directory with -L, it doesn't help. still many undefined references. is there any possible reasons for the undefined references

Comment: Dunno. I added an example above. Hopefully someone more familiar with your compiler and OS will chime in. By the way, what **is** your compiler and OS? I think it's sort of relevant... ;-) Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hopefully, I can get more help

Comment: @leo: possibly the above is all you need. Try the example. Cheers,

Comment: @leo: or, simply copy or rename the lib. :-)

Comment: Well, simply rename it doesn't work, some incompatible problem happened. And your example, I typed that step by step, when I try to generate executable file from main.o, I got "main.o: In function 'main': main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to 'foo()' collect2:ld returned 1 exit status" Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Huh. You wrote `g++ main.o lib/foolib.a` and got that "undefined reference" message?

Comment: yepp. g++ main.o lib/foolib.a then got that message